# How to use new line character inside EL string literal?

Tags: jsp, el

I need to print some text with multiple lines inside a text area using EL. When I do this:

```
<textarea rows="4">
    ${o.condition ? "blah" : "1. \n2. \n3. \n4."}
</textarea>
```

I get:

> Unable to compile class for JSP

What is the equivalent to

```
<%=o.getCondition() ? "blah" : "1. \n2. \n3. \n4." %>
```

using EL?

Some suggest storing `\n` in a variable and using this variable within the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the EL implementation used, you may need to escape the backslash as well. As far as I'm concerned, this is true for Apache's EL implementation (as used in a.o. Tomcat, WebSphere, etc), but not for Oracle's EL implementation (as used in a.o. GlassFish, WildFly, etc). EL spec is itself not fully clear on this (yet).

```
<textarea rows="4">
    ${o.condition ? "blah" : "1. \\n2. \\n3. \\n4."}
</textarea>
```

But safer is to use the HTML entity notation instead. Linefeed is [character `U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) which can in hexadecimal HTML entity notation be represented as `&#xa;`.

```
<textarea rows="4">
    ${o.condition ? "blah" : "1. &#xa;2. &#xa;3. &#xa;4."}
</textarea>
```

This way you're not dependent on the target runtime.

Comment: The first option just prints the \n under Apache EL. The second works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use jstl tags,You can achieve it like this.

```
<textarea rows="4">
<c:forTokens items="1.\n2.\n3.\n4." delims="\n" var="item">
     ${item} 
</c:forTokens>
</textarea>
```

Comment: My expression is more complicated. It's like

${condition ? "blah" : "1. \n2. \n3. \n4."}

So, I can't use `<c:forTokens>` because it won't work inside the expression.